# How can you imitate a (specific) browser when using a webview?

Tags: android, browser, webview

In my App I use a webview to open a website. On that website there is a javascript that causes an error. Now, I know that this website uses browser detection and I believe that this might be the problem why the page appears as a blank page in my webview.

Is there a way to somehow imitate a browser so if the js tries to detect the browser it will not fail?

Here is my WebViewClient:

```
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ssl error:" + error);
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(<Set the Browser NameString>);
```

The above setting might help you. It might be the case that `userAgentString` will set the browser type as well